# WebLogic servers (installed as a windows service) automatically stop

Tags: oracle-12c

I have installed Oracle Database 12c Release 2, along with Oracle WebLogic Server 12c (12.2.1.4) and Oracle Forms and Reports 12c on my system, according to the documentation provided in the main website, as well as other sources.

The WebLogic servers (which include AdminServer, WLS_FORMS and WLS_REPORTS) run properly when being started from the cmd files (startWebLogic.cmd, startManagedWebLogic.cmd). I want these servers to start automatically as a Windows service; after installing and then restarting the system, the servers' status show as 'Running', but 10-15 minutes in and it all gets stopped.

Below is my script to install the AdminServer Windows Service:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL
set DOMAIN_NAME=base_domain
set USERDOMAIN_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain
set SERVER_NAME=AdminServer
set WL_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver
set PRODUCTION_MODE=true
call "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd"
call "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\bin\installSvc.cmd"
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

And below is the script for installing the Forms and Reports server:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL
set DOMAIN_NAME=base_domain
set USERDOMAIN_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain
set SERVER_NAME=WLS_FORMS
set ADMIN_URL=http://desktop-q9fv7np:7001
set WL_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver
set PRODUCTION_MODE=true
call "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd"
call "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\bin\installSvc.cmd"
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

*the only change being SERVER_NAME=WLS_REPORTS, in case of Reports

The AdminServer log file shows the following:

```
####<28-Oct-2019 12:35:52,984 o'clock GST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <DESKTOP-Q9FV7NP> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <37f82e0f-2e4a-4618-a72f-a296d7fd4526-00000002> <1572251752984> <[severity-value: 4] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason: 

There are 1 nested errors:

oracle.security.jps.JpsException: JPS-01055: Could not create credential store instance. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreException: Can not connect DB with URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@//desktop-q9fv7np:50000/LIGINODB]
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.config.OpssCommonStartup.start(OpssCommonStartup.java:228)
    at oracle.security.jps.wls.JpsWlsStartup.start(JpsWlsStartup.java:105)
    at oracle.security.jps.JpsStartup.startWithRetry(JpsStartup.java:287)
    at oracle.security.jps.JpsStartup.start(JpsStartup.java:252)
    at oracle.security.jps.wls.JpsDefaultService.start(JpsDefaultService.java:92)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredStoreException: JPS-01055: Could not create credential store instance. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreException: Can not connect DB with URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@//desktop-q9fv7np:50000/LIGINODB]
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.LdapCredentialStore.init(LdapCredentialStore.java:191)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.LdapCredentialStore.start(LdapCredentialStore.java:1030)
    at oracle.security.opss.internal.runtime.ServiceContextImpl.start(ServiceContextImpl.java:220)
    at oracle.security.opss.internal.runtime.ServiceContextManagerImpl.createDefaultContext(ServiceContextManagerImpl.java:325)
    at oracle.security.opss.internal.runtime.ServiceContextManagerImpl.initialize(ServiceContextManagerImpl.java:242)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.config.OpssCommonStartup$1.run(OpssCommonStartup.java:166)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.config.OpssCommonStartup.start(OpssCommonStartup.java:159)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreException: Can not connect DB with URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@//desktop-q9fv7np:50000/LIGINODB]
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.util.JpsDataManagerUtil.getDBConnection(JpsDataManagerUtil.java:407)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.util.JpsDataManagerUtil.isNewSchema(JpsDataManagerUtil.java:249)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datamanager.DataManagerFactoryImpl.isNewSchema(DataManagerFactoryImpl.java:252)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datamanager.DataManagerFactoryImpl.getDBDataManager(DataManagerFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datamanager.DataManagerFactoryImpl.getDataManager(DataManagerFactoryImpl.java:161)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.rdbms.CsfDbmsManager.getDataManager(CsfDbmsManager.java:95)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.CsfStoreManager.existsStore(CsfStoreManager.java:298)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.CsfStoreManager.completeInit(CsfStoreManager.java:177)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.rdbms.CsfDbmsManager.<init>(CsfDbmsManager.java:91)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.rdbms.CsfDbmsManager.createInstance(CsfDbmsManager.java:72)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.CsfStoreManager.getInstance(CsfStoreManager.java:121)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.LdapCredentialStore.init(LdapCredentialStore.java:188)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12528, TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:702)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.util.JpsDataManagerUtil.getDBConnection(JpsDataManagerUtil.java:400)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12528, TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:271)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
    ... 52 more

> 
####<28-Oct-2019 12:35:54,452 o'clock GST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <DESKTOP-Q9FV7NP> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <37f82e0f-2e4a-4618-a72f-a296d7fd4526-00000002> <1572251754452> <[severity-value: 32] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.> 
####<28-Oct-2019 12:35:54,453 o'clock GST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <DESKTOP-Q9FV7NP> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <37f82e0f-2e4a-4618-a72f-a296d7fd4526-00000002> <1572251754453> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down.> 
####<28-Oct-2019 12:35:54,460 o'clock GST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <DESKTOP-Q9FV7NP> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <37f82e0f-2e4a-4618-a72f-a296d7fd4526-00000002> <1572251754460> <[severity-value: 32] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.> 
####<28-Oct-2019 12:35:54,466 o'clock GST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <DESKTOP-Q9FV7NP> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <37f82e0f-2e4a-4618-a72f-a296d7fd4526-00000003> <1572251754466> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000236> <Stopping execute threads.> 
####<28-Oct-2019 12:35:54,522 o'clock GST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <DESKTOP-Q9FV7NP> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <37f82e0f-2e4a-4618-a72f-a296d7fd4526-00000002> <1572251754522> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000238> <Shutdown has completed.>
```

I have been trying to find out the fault for weeks, and it is now urgent. I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the error stack you shared, you will see a clue as to the reason for the shutdown.  It appears the database is not accessible.  Likely this means it has crashed or been shutdown intentionally.  The WLS Repository Database is required to be accessible through the life of the running servers.  In other words, you cannot stop the WLS Repo database and expect the WLS servers to remain healthy. Check the db logs for details. You might need to do some db tuning.

If it is the case that you believe the db has not been stop and is working correctly, then something else is blocking the WLS tier from accessing the database properly.

Here is a snippet of the error stack you shared with the relevant statements in bold.

oracle.security.jps.JpsException: JPS-01055: **Could not create credential store instance**. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreException: **Can not connect DB** with URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@//desktop-q9fv7np:50000/LIGINODB]
...
Caused by: oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredStoreException: JPS-01055: **Could not create credential store instance**. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreException: **Can not connect DB** with URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@//desktop-q9fv7np:50000/LIGINODB]